# How to override create method in specific custom module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-14

I have custom module with class `helpdesk.ticket` that overrides create method and adds new features:

```
# helpdesk.ticket    
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    res = super(HelpdeskTicket, self).create(vals)
    res.do_something()
    return res
```

And I am working on second module that inherits (only _inherit) from `helpdesk.ticket` and I need to add a condition into the `helpdesk.ticket` create method.

Dream solution for me would be:

1. Create method in second module is called
2. if condition is True then call the original `helpdesk.ticket` create method.

It would be nice if that could be done but it might be wishful thinking from me.

Acceptable solution:

1. Copy paste original `helpdesk.ticket` create method in second module and manually add condition (i.e. rewriting `helpdesk.ticket` create method)

I tried to do this but for some reason **both** of the create methods are called (I called super in second module).

Help would definitely be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before. You should change 'HelpdeskTicket' to 'models.Model' to only call your custom create method instead of the inherited create method. Hope this helps.

```
class HelpdeskTicketCustom(models.Model):
    _inherit = "helpdesk.ticket"   

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals):
        res = super(models.Model, self).create(vals)
        res.do_something()
        return res
```